# How to return custom http header codes nextjs 13 server actions?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

How to return custom HTTP header codes nextjs 13 server actions?
Like imagine we are calling some endpoint, or we are reading some value from somewhere,
and we need to return some json with a specific HTTP status code.

Comment: Server components do not return JSON, they return react components that are rendered into static html, so there is no need for custom status codes.

Comment: @FabioNettis I am asking about server actions not server components

Comment: As seen [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/49302), there is no way to return a custom status code from server actions either.